# Symfony Doctrine Check if ID of relations in cascade OneToMany Never BE value

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine

I'm working on symfony, and i have a doctrine problem :

```
class Utilisateur implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{ /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=UserGestionnaire::class, mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $userGestionnaires;
```

```
class UserGestionnaire
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Societe::class, inversedBy="userGestionnaires")
     */
    private $gestionnaire;
```

So here i have a One To Many Relation,and i want to Know how Many user don t have the the usergestionnaire gestionnaire id 1002

I tried a lot of testing and searching, but i didn t found any solution,
Here what i got so far :

```
public function countUserNoIdSpecificGest()
    {
        $limitDate = date_format(new \DateTime("now - 2 years"), 'Y-m-d');
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');
        $queryB = $query
            ->select('count(distinct(u.id))')
            ->join('u.mouvements', 'm')
            ->join('u.userGestionnaires', 'ug')
            ->join('ug.gestionnaire', 'sg')
            // Here :  ->andWhere('sg.id NEVER BE 1002')
            ->join('m.rules', 'r')
            ->join('r.avenantModule', 'am')
            ->join('am.module', 'mod')
            ->join('mod.manager', 's')
            ->andWhere('s.id = 1002')
            ->andWhere('u.deletedAt IS NULL')
            ->andWhere('m.deletedAt IS NULL')
            ->andWhere(
                $query->expr()->orX(
                    $query->expr()->orX(
                        $query->expr()->gte('m.dateOut', ':limitDate'),
                    )
                )
            )
            ->setParameter('limitDate', $limitDate)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getSingleScalarResult();

        return $queryB;
    }
```

To be more understandable, here is the part of the PHP code that I would like to transfer to WHERE doctrine :

```
        $usersNotVerified = $this->em->getRepository(Utilisateur::class)->getUserNoIdSpecificGest();
        $users = array();
        foreach ($usersNotVerified as $userNotVerified) {
            $gestionnaires = $userNotVerified->getUserGestionnaires();
            $finded = false;
            foreach ($gestionnaires as $gestionnaire) {
                $societyId = $gestionnaire->getGestionnaire()->getId();
                if ($societyId == 1002) {
                    $finded = true;
                }
            }
            if (!$finded) {
                array_push($users, $userNotVerified);
            }
        }
        $countNoId = count($users);
```

```
    public function getUserNoIdSpecificGest()
    {
        $limitDate = date_format(new \DateTime("now - 2 years"), 'Y-m-d');
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');
        $queryB = $query
            ->join('u.mouvements', 'm')
            ->join('m.rules', 'r')
            ->join('r.avenantModule', 'am')
            ->join('am.module', 'mod')
            ->join('mod.manager', 's')
            ->andWhere('s.id = 1002')
            ->andWhere('u.deletedAt IS NULL')
            ->andWhere('m.deletedAt IS NULL')
            ->andWhere(
                $query->expr()->orX(
                    $query->expr()->orX(
                        $query->expr()->gte('m.dateOut', ':limitDate'),
                    )
                )
            )
            ->setParameter('limitDate', $limitDate)
            ->addOrderBy('u.id', 'asc')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();

        return $queryB;
    }
```

Comment: add where condition like this `->where('SIZE(u.userGestionnaires) = 0')`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but userGestionnaires is a One  to Many relation, so they can have for exemple id 1001, 1000 and 1002, and i only want all User that don t have userGestionnaires id 1002

Comment: then use `->andWhere('ug.id != 1002')`

Comment: Since it's a One To Many relation, your answer not working because ug.id could be 1001 and 1002, I edited my question to be more clear